# gcc header file not found with google protocol buffer

Tags: c++, gcc, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use the `gcc` command to compile and run a `.cpp` file to test google protobuf.

CPP_TEST.cpp

```
#include "GameInfo.pb.h"

int main() {
   // ...
}
```

GameInfo.pb.h  generated by `protoc`

```
#ifndef PROTOBUF_GameInfo_2eproto__INCLUDED
#define PROTOBUF_GameInfo_2eproto__INCLUDED

#include <string>

#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
// ...
```

and my files in folder looks like this

```
- test
    CPP_TEST.cpp
    GameInfo.pb.h
    GameInfo.pb.cc

    // the lib file for protobuf
    libprotobuf.a

    // the srouce code of protobuf
    - google
        - protobuf
            // ...
            - stubs
                common.h
                // ...
```

and then I tried to compile the `.cpp` file

```
gcc CPP_TEST.cpp -l ./google -o OUT_CPP_TEST
```

But get the error:

```
#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
```

I think it is an error with the gcc compiler flag but can not figure out why...

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

UPDATE:

After changing the command to

```
gcc CPP_TEST.cpp -I./ -o OUT_CPP_TEST
```

The file is ok to compiler and run.

But if I add a code to the `main` function :

```
game::info::GameInfo gameInfoOut;
```

And compiler it will fail with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "game::info::GameInfo::GameInfo()", referenced from:
      _main in CPP_TEST-9245ef.o
  "game::info::GameInfo::~GameInfo()", referenced from:
      _main in CPP_TEST-9245ef.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So I tried to add the `libprotobuf.a` file to gcc command

```
gcc CPP_TEST.cpp -L./ -lprotobuf -I./ -o CPP_TEST_OUT
```

But I am still getting the same error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "game::info::GameInfo::GameInfo()", referenced from:
      _main in CPP_TEST-0e3576.o
  "game::info::GameInfo::~GameInfo()", referenced from:
      _main in CPP_TEST-0e3576.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

UPDATE:

I tried to complier and link all the files step by step like:

```
gcc -c -I./ GameInfo.pb.cc 
gcc -c -I./ GameEnum.pb.cc 
gcc -c -I./ CPP_TEST.cpp
```

and link

```
gcc CPP_TEST.o GameInfo.pb.o GameEnum.pb.o -L./ -lprotobuf -o main
```

And now I am getting bunch of errors like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___dynamic_cast", referenced from:
      game::info::RoleInfo const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<game::info::RoleInfo const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*) in GameInfo.pb.o
      game::info::ItemInfo const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<game::info::ItemInfo const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*) in GameInfo.pb.o
      game::info::GameInfo const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<game::info::GameInfo const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*) in GameInfo.pb.o
      google::protobuf::FileDescriptorSet const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorSet const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*) in libprotobuf.a(descriptor.pb.o)
      google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*) in libprotobuf.a(descriptor.pb.o)
      google::protobuf::DescriptorProto_ExtensionRange const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<google::protobuf::DescriptorProto_ExtensionRange const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*) in libprotobuf.a(descriptor.pb.o)
      google::protobuf::DescriptorProto const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<google::protobuf::DescriptorProto const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*) in libprotobuf.a(descriptor.pb.o)
      ...
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      game::enumeration::protobuf_AssignDesc_GameEnum_2eproto() in GameEnum.pb.o
      google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInit(long*, void (*)()) in GameEnum.pb.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in GameEnum.pb.o
      game::info::protobuf_AssignDesc_GameInfo_2eproto() in GameInfo.pb.o
      game::info::protobuf_AddDesc_GameInfo_2eproto() in GameInfo.pb.o
      game::info::RoleInfo::RoleInfo() in GameInfo.pb.o
      game::info::RoleInfo::RoleInfo(game::info::RoleInfo const&) in GameInfo.pb.o
      // more here
```

It is really weird since the I can complier and run it successfully in the xcode with all the GameInfo.pb.h/cc GameEnum.pb.h/cc, libprotobuf.a and "google source".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc doesn't know the include directory of google headers until you mention the path using `-I` flag not `-l`. As `google` directory is in the current working directory so no need to pass `./google` for `-I`.

`g++ -I./ CPP_TEST.cpp -o OUT_CPP_TEST`

or else you can just use what your error suggestion said (use quotes instead of angles) because your file hierarchy matches this suggestion.

```
#include "google/protobuf/stubs/common.h"
```

Comment: @supersuraccoon I should have used current directory `-I./` instead of `-I./google`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It compilers and runs fine after using the "-I./" flag...   But now I am having trouble linking the libprotobuf.a file. Can you check the UPDATE of this Question ? Thanks :)

Comment: The lib is a fat file and supports X86_64. lipo -info outputs :  Architectures in the fat file: libprotobuf.a are: armv7s armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64

Comment: @supersuraccoon The problem is not with the libprotobuf.a, `game::info::GameInfo::GameInfo()` and `~GameInfo()` methods may not be defined in your code or you forgot to link that corresponding object file.

Comment: You are right, I think I need to compiler and link the GameInfo.pb.cc, GameEnum.pb.cc together with CPP_TEST.cpp file. But I am still getting weird errors ... (You can check the UPDATE)

Comment: @supersuraccoon compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`

Comment: You right! Changing the gcc to g++ finally works !  Thanks a lot for your help :)